# Why i'm getting exception: ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

This is the code:

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
long filel = readStream.ReadToEnd().Length;
readStream.Close();
FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(ftpdirectories + "\\" + filenameonly, FileMode.Create);
string fnn = ftpdirectories + "\\" + filenameonly;
int Length = 2048;
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
```

The exception is on the line:

```
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
```

If i'm not using the StreamReader the long and the Close it's working fine but once i'm adding the StreamReader i'm getting the exception.

Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

```
 System.ObjectDisposedException was caught
      HResult=-2146232798
      Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
      Source=System
      ObjectName=System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
      StackTrace:
           at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
           at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
           at FTP_ProgressBar.FtpProgress.DownloadFtpContent(Object sender, String file, String filesdirectories, String fn) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\FtpProgress.cs:line 284
      InnerException:
```

Line 284 is:

```
int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

> [ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception(v=vs.110).aspx): The exception that is thrown when an operation is performed on a disposed object.

when you close `readStream`

```
readStream.Close();
```

> [StreamReader.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Closes the StreamReader object and the underlying stream, and releases any system resources associated with the reader. This implementation of Close calls the Dispose method passing a true value.

the underlying `responseStream` which is set in

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, ...
```

is closed and closing a stream call dispose method and it get disposed. after that you access `responseStream` and boom! `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: And is there way to do something ? To read the file size with StreamReader without disposing the stream ? My ftp server not allow me to use ContentLength so i tried to use StreamReader and the StreamReader does get the file size but also make the disposing.

Comment: you should use `using` and do what you want inside your `using` block, so after that the resources are disposed automatically
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: You are going to run to a even bigger problem, to get the total length you read in the entire stream, but it appears you are trying to make a progress bar for the read. What is the point of a progress bar if you just waited the entire download time to figure out how big your progress bar should be?

Comment: Scott then i should somehow to make the reading inside the while loop and reporting it there ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Stream` gets closed and disposed when the `StreamReader` gets closed. Check out the MSDN page on the `StreamReader` [Close method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

To wit, the `StreamReader`'s Close method

> Closes the StreamReader object and the underlying stream, and releases any system resources associated with the reader.

Along with that:

> This implementation of Close calls the Dispose method passing a true value.

Answer (score 0):

You using..

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Provide encoding required for response as follows.

```
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252"));
```

This happens with German characters like ü, ö, ä etc. So probably UTF-8 fails while reading and closes the stream. Hence, you need to maintain encoding list against URLs or expected response and pass it as above.